# How do I get gtsummary to exponentiate a weibull model?

Tags: gtsummary, survival

I'm running a Weibull regression using the survreg function in the survival package.

I'd like to use gtsummary to then produce a table of the results.

But when I try to exponentiate the beta coefficient, it just returns me the same beta value - but says it's exp(B) in the header.

reprex:

```
library(survival)
library(gtsummary)

fit_w<-survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, dist='weibull', data=lung)

tbl_regression(fit_w)

tbl_regression(fit_w,
               exponentiate=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default tidying function is `broom::tidy.survreg()` which does NOT have an exponentiate argument for `survreg()` models. The reason it is not there is because most of the models created with this function are NOT proportional hazards models, meaning that you should not exponentiate because the result is not a hazard ratio.

If you confidently feel like your model should have an exponentiated coef, then you can write a small wrapper for `broom::tidy.survreg()` that includes a exponentiate argument.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this here, it's not pretty but does the job!

`library(survival)`

`library(gtsummary)`

`fit_w<-survreg(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, dist='weibull', data=lung)`

`tbl_regression(fit_w)`

`tbl_regression(fit_w, exponentiate = TRUE, tidy_fun = function(x, ...) broom::tidy(x, ...) %>% dplyr::filter(.data$term != "Log(scale)")%>% mutate(across(all_of(c("estimate", "conf.low", "conf.high")), ~exp(.))))`

The `exponentiate = TRUE` makes sure the header shows as exp(Beta) on the table, the tidy_fun is the default tidy_fun for survreg() functions (see https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_regression_methods.html) but I added the mutate bit to it to make it exponentiate the estimates and the confidence intervals.

I've found this helpful for summary tables with AFTs using the Acceleration Factor.